# How to return array of custom objects?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a function that would return an array of custom objects. Here is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Public Type Node
     mValue As Integer
     mTo() As Integer
End Type

Function FillData()
    Dim a As Node
    Dim b As Node
    Dim c As Node
    Dim nody() As Node

    a.mValue = 1
    ReDim a.mTo(0 To 1)
    a.mTo(0) = 2

    b.mValue = 2
    ReDim b.mTo(0 To 1)
    b.mTo(0) = 3

    c.mValue = 3
    ReDim c.mTo(0 To 1)
    c.mTo(0) = 1

    ReDim nody(0 To 2)
    nody(0) = a
    nody(1) = b
    nody(2) = c

    FillData = nody
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim data() As Node
    data = FillData()
End Sub
```

The problem is that when I try to run it (test sub) I get a compilation error in `FillData = nody` that says:

> only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions

My entire code is in a public module. How do I 'coerce' a function to return an array of custom objects?

Comment: Use a class module

Comment: As Ron said. Here is an example using Class and collection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049798/compile-error-only-user-defined-types-defined-in-public-object-modules-can-be-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the return value of function.

```
Option Explicit

Public Type Node
     mValue As Integer
     mTo() As Integer
End Type

Function FillData() As Node()
    Dim a As Node
    Dim b As Node
    Dim c As Node
    Dim nody() As Node

    a.mValue = 1
    ReDim a.mTo(0 To 1)
    a.mTo(0) = 2

    b.mValue = 2
    ReDim b.mTo(0 To 1)
    b.mTo(0) = 3

    c.mValue = 3
    ReDim c.mTo(0 To 1)
    c.mTo(0) = 1

    ReDim nody(0 To 2)
    nody(0) = a
    nody(1) = b
    nody(2) = c

    FillData = nody
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim data() As Node
    data = FillData()
End Sub
```